# MemoryError with large sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

For a project I have built a program that constructs large matrices.

```
def ExpandSparse(LNew):
SpId = ssp.csr_matrix(np.identity(MS))
Sz = MS**LNew
HNew = ssp.csr_matrix((Sz,Sz))
Bulk = dict()
for i in range(LNew-1):
    for j in range(LNew-1):
        if i == j:
            Bulk[(i,j)]=H2
        else:
            Bulk[(i,j)]=SpId
Ha = ssp.csr_matrix((8,8))
try:
    for i in range(LNew-1):
        for j in range(LNew-2):
            if j < 1:
                Ha = ssp.csr_matrix(ssp.kron(Bulk[(i,j)],Bulk[(i,j+1)]))
            else:
                Ha = ssp.csr_matrix(ssp.kron(Ha,Bulk[(i,j+1)]))
        HNew = HNew + Ha
except MemoryError:
    print('The matrix you tried to build requires too much memory space.')
    return
return HNew
```

This does the job, however it does not work as well as I would have expected. The problem is that it won't allow for really large matrices. When `LNew`is larger than 13 I will get a MemoryError. My experiences with numpy suggest that, memorywise, I should be able to get `LNew` up to 18 or 19 before I get this error. Does this have to do with my code, or with the way `scipy.sparse.kron()` works with these matrices?

Another note that might be important is that I use Windows not Linux.

Comment: Could you supply a self-contained example, where all variables are defined? For instance, what is the value of `MS`?

Comment: MS in this case is 2. H2 is a 4 x 4 matrix defined as: `H2 = ssp.csr_matrix(np.array([[0.25,0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,-0.25,0.5,0.0],[0.0,0.5,-0.25,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.25]]))
` Where ssp is scipy.sparse

Comment: What's the size of the largest `Ha`that you can construct?  I'm thinking of shape, an more importantly the number of nonzeros.  Roughly speaking a sparse matrix with `N` nonzero terms will store the data in  3 arrays `(N,)` long (2 of those will be int dtype).

Comment: The largest `Ha` I can construct is 8192 x 8192, where there are 55496 stored elements in CSR format. So as I mentioned it is strange that with numpy I can calculate a dense matrix of 4096 x 4096, but here I can't exceed a sparse matrix with 55496 nonzero elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more reading on the working of the `scipy.sparse.kron()` function I have noticed that there is a third term named format you can enter. The default setting is None, but when it is put on 'csr' or another supported format it will only use the sparse format making it a lot more efficient, now for me it can build a 2097152 x 2097152 matrix. Here `LNew` is 21.